# Como cargar un archivo de excel que se encuentra en un folder contenido en la misma ruta del .exe?

Tags: c#, excel

Me encuentro desarrollando una WFA que se utiliza como una base de datos a base de un documento de excel (.xlsx), el contenido del documento provee a la base de datos de información con la cual trabaja el usuario, actualmente ***el programa funciona sin ningún problema cuando el usuario carga manualmente el archivo de excel***, pero es necesario que el usuario no tenga interacción con el archivo, por lo que he intentado inicializar el documento de manera automática. Cuando intento eso, Visual Studio me indica el siguiente error:

"System.ObjectDisposedException: 'Cannot access a disposed object."

El documento se encuentra en un folder dentro de otro, que a su vez  se encuentran en el mismo folder que contiene el .exe.

He intentado hacer lo siguiente:

```
string path = Application.StartupPath;
string file = @"Resources\db\tabla.xlsx";
string full = Path.Combine(path,file);
```

El resultado de *full* me da lo siguiente:

*C:\Usuario\Documentos\Solucion\Bin\Debug\Resources\db\tabla.xlsx*

donde

C:\usuario\documentos\solucion\

es la ubicacion del folder que contiene el .exe y

Resources\db\tabla.xlsx

es la ubicación del archivo que intento cargar.

Adjunto los fragmentos de codigo correspondiente de la manera manual y automatica con la que cargo el archivo de excel:

Manual

```
Using system.reflection;
Using Excel = Microsoft.office.interop.excel;

    Public partial class Form1 : Form
{

Excel.application oXL;
Excel._woorkbook oWB;
Excel._worksheet oST;
Object misvalue = system.reflection.missing.value;

Public Form1
{

InitializeComponent();
Openfiledialog open = new openfiledialog();
Open.restoredirectory = true;

Messagebox.show("Selecciona la base de datos a usar");

If (open.showdialog() != Dialogresult.cancel)
{
Try 
{
oXL= new Excel.application();
oXL.visible = false;
oXL.Usercontrol = true;

oWB = (oXL.workbooks.open(FileName));
oST =
(Excel._worksheet)oWB.sheets.get_Item("sheet1");

Etc.
}
Catch (exception)
{
Messagebox.show("ocurrio un error al cargar la base de datos");
oXL.quit();
This.close();
}
}
}

}
```

Automatico

```
 Using system.reflection;
    Using Excel = Microsoft.office.interop.excel;

        Public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

    Excel.application oXL;
    Excel._woorkbook oWB;
    Excel._worksheet oST;
    Object misvalue = system.reflection.missing.value;

    Public Form1
    {

    InitializeComponent();
    String path=application.startuppath;
String file = @"Resources\db\tabla.xlsx";
    String full=path.combine(path,file);

    Try 
    {
    oXL= new Excel.application();
    oXL.visible = false;
    oXL.Usercontrol = true;

    oWB = oXL.workbooks.open(full);
    oST =
    (Excel._worksheet)oWB.sheets.get_Item("sheet1");

    Etc.
    }
    Catch (exception)
    {
    Messagebox.show("ocurrio un error al cargar la base de datos");
    oXL.quit();
    This.close();
    }
    }

    }
```

Tengo 2 preguntas respecto a esto:

1- Como es la forma correcta para hacer que un archivo contenido en los folderes correspondientes a la raiz del folder del .exe se ejecute?

2- Que implica que el error antes mencionado salte? (he notado que se debe a la incapacidad de cargar el documento de excel)

Comment: La forma de acceder al archivo es correcta por medio del StartupPath- Ahora el mensaje de error que mencionas donde se produce ? porque no creo que tenga relacion  con el acceso al excel

Comment: Leandro, el error salta al momento de iniciar el programa, tengo un try que contiene todo el proceso de inicializacion de excel, para ser preciso al hacer el avanze del proceso paso por paso el error ocurre a la hora de cargar el workbook, que después me redirige al constructor del diseñador y dice que no pudo acceder al Form.

Comment: podrias poner el codigo que utilizas para trabajar el excel ? esta claro que intentas acceder a un objeto que no esta instanciado pro eso el mensaje de error

Comment: Suena logico lo que dices, pero es raro que literalmente lo unico que cambia de la version manual a la automatica es la manera en la que inicio el workbook. He editado la pregunta con el codigo con el que inicio el excel de las 2 maneras.

Comment: Cuando seleccionas un excel de form manual de que carpeta lo tomas ? no te animas a usar alguna librerias basada en open xml? o sea dejar de usar las api de office

Comment: El archivo esta en la misma carpeta, en la misma ubicación, de momento no puedo cambiarlo, es una version prototipo y se requiere dar resultados con el excel por que es lo que me proporcionaron, en un futuro tal vez podria cambiar a algo mas accesible como SQL Lite o incluso probar la libreria que me compentas.

Comment: pero yo apuntaba a librerias open xml no a una base de datos, por ejemplo utilizar Closed Xml https://github.com/closedxml/closedxml  de esta forma no tendras que pelearte con las librerias COM de office

Comment: Ah, ya veo, le dare un vistazo en cuanto pueda.

Comment: Entonces el error puedo suponer que es por culpa mia o es por el como maneja visual studio los interop de excel?